# setting div height to fill remaining height

Tags: html, css

I am making a card view. What is shown here is an extremely reduced form.
I cannot get the `.main` div to expand automatically to fill the remaining vertical space on hover.

One way that I found on StackOverflow is to use absolute positioning. I am not very critical of it, but when I ever need to change, say, the font size of description, I'll have to change the `bottom` bound as well, else there'd be an overlap.

Is there a workaround or a CSS property (for height, in this case) to do this?
Anything that does not require the height of `.foot` div?

```css
div.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #171812;
  background: #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  height: 250px;
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.main {
  height: 100px;      /*<<<< HERE*/
  background: #f00;   /*for development purpose*/
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.foot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="head">Name</div>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w5U482j.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="foot">
    Description
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), pay attention to [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property. Also, you don't need to use [position: absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) here:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    color: #171812;
    background: #a0a0a0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.wrapper:hover {
    height: 250px;
}

.head {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.main {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
}

img {
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.foot {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="head">Name</div>
    <div class="main">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w5U482j.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="foot">Description</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/zfb7mfph/1/)

Comment: It does what I am looking for. Does it have fairly good support?

Comment: Also, I noted `calc()`. That looks cool! Didn't know 'bout that. Thanks!

Comment: @frederick99 I'm glad to help. `flex` is supported enough now, but you should pay attention to vendor prefixes and IE10 (it supports another standard) — [CanIUse?](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Comment: Is it possible to change, say, the image border, when I hover over the `.wrapper` div?

Comment: @frederick99 yeah, why not? Check out [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/zfb7mfph/2/).